# Помогите разобрать XML с пространством имен

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Доброе время суток!
Бьюсь уже неделю, не могу распарсить XML вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header xmlns:ser="http://www.a-3.ru/partners/services/"/>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:ser="http://www.a-3.ru/partners/services/">
        <ser:getPenaltiesResponse>
            <result>
                <resCode>0</resCode>
            </result>
            <penalties>
                <penalty billNumber="18810152160623063633" billDate="2016-06-23" validUntil="2016-08-23" amount="500" addInfo="ШТРАФ ПО АДМИНИСТРАТИВНОМУ ПРАВОНАРУШЕНИЮ ПОСТАНОВЛЕНИЕ №18810152160623063633;Подразделение: ЦАФАП ОДД ГИБДД ГУ МВД России по Нижегородской области;Получатель: УФК по Нижегородской области (ГУ МВД России по Нижегородской области);Банк Получателя: Волго-Вятское ГУ Банка России;Номер счёта Получателя: 40101810400000010002;ИНН: 5260040766;КПП: 526001001;БИК Банка Получателя: 042202001;ОКАТО: 22701000;КБК: 18811630020016000140;" regCert="52СМ499648" docName="regCert" docNumber="52СМ499648" payStatus="0" quittance="3"/>
            </penalties>
        </ser:getPenaltiesResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Загружаю ответ от сервера: `$result = simplexml_load_string($result);`
Дальше разбираю следующим способом, так как имеется пространство имен:

```
$namespaces = $result->getNamespaces(true);
$ser = $result->children($namespaces['ser']);
$body = $ser->getPenaltiesResponse;
```

А дальше просто не понимаю как добраться к элеменуту `resCode` или `penalty`.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала встречный вопрос: зачем вы явно кусок `SOAP` пытаетесь распарсить вручную? В PHP есть штатный [клиент](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) для всего протокола.

Ну а если это не SOAP, несмотря на характерный namespace, то достучаться можно вот так:

```
$result = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$response = $result->children('soapenv', true)
            ->Body
            ->children('ser', true)
            ->getPenaltiesResponse
            ->children(null);

var_dump((string) $response->result->resCode);
var_dump((string) $response->penalties->penalty->attributes()->billNumber);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло. Да там не понятно гибрид SOAP какой то используется, вот и приходиться парсингом заниматься. Огромное спасибо еще раз.

Comment: А Вы не подскажете еще как определить существование `$response->penalties`, он не всегда просто существует пробовал `isset` для атрибута `$response->penalties->penalty->attributes()->billNumber` не работает.

Comment: Вот за это я simplexml и не люблю, он излишне услужливо работает и в итоге непонятно, а что есть вообще в документе и какой структуры. Попробуйте `$response->penalties->count()`. Если элемента нет, то будет 0.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Выручили!

Comment: Здравствуйте, я уже Вас замучал, но помогите распарсить xml еще одного типа у нас их всего две будет, я по вашему принципу делаю но ничего не получается, не могу добраться до `resCode` и `resMessage`

Comment: `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:ser="http://www.a-3.ru/partners/services/"/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:checkPaymentResponse xmlns:ser="http://www.a-3.ru/partners/services/">
         <result>
            <resCode>0</resCode>
            <resMessage>Операция выполнена успешно</resMessage>
         </result>
      </ser:checkPaymentResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Comment: Ответил на письмо, но сюда для красоты тоже продублирую: после `$result->children('soapenv', true)->Body->children('ser', true)->checkPaymentResponse->children(null)->result` получится объект с нужными свойствами.